# Laravel Query Builder firstOrFail()?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm

When I use Query Builder I Always find myself doing something like this:

```
    $item = \DB::table('table')->where('slug',$slug)->first();

    if ($item===null)
        throw \Exception('Not found');
```

This could be easly solved if there were a firstOrFail() like Eloquent:

```
$item = \DB::table('table')->where('slug',$slug)->firstOrFail();
```

Is Eloquent the only way to use `firstOrFail()`? Does Query Builder allow something like this?

Comment: You could extend the Illuminate builder, add the method and replace the `DB` facade. May I ask why you're not using Eloquent here? :)

Comment: it's a simple query where I need a single field, I don't think i need Eloquent here

Comment: The whole idea behind Eloquent (and ORM's in general) is that you create a model representing your data (in your case, a DB table); I'd say that if you use Eloquent or you use a Facade, you will have an almost equal amount of overhead. Eloquent is just more readable. You could make a performance test if you wanted :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add it yourself to the query builder, via a macro:

```php
DB::query()->macro('firstOrFail', function () {
    if ($record = $this->first()) {
        return $record;
    }

    throw new Exception('No records found');
});
```

Then you can use it the same way you do Eloquent:

```php
$item = DB::table('table')->where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: nice, this should be pushed to github/laravel

Comment: Keep in mind that eloquent throws a ModelNotFound exception if the model isn't found. Which means that an unhandled exception would return a 404, whereas using this would return a 500.

Answer (score 1):

you are almost there, laravel does provide a way to check something like this

```
DB::table('table')->where('slug', $slug)->exists()

DB::table('table')->where('slug', $slug)->doesntExist()
```

it will return boolean, hope this helps

Update:
how i did it in projects was

```
function checkIfExists($table, $value, $field = 'id'){
    return DB::table($table)->where($field, $value)->exists()
}
function getFirst($table, $value, $field = 'id'){
    return DB::table($table)->where($field, $value)->first()
}
```

and then use this function like this

```
if(checkIfExists('users', 2))
    $user = getFirst('users', 2)
else
    // throw exception or something
```

Hope this helps

Comment: firstOrFail() is another thing. Should return the item if it exists, expection if it doesn't

Comment: how i did it was, i put exists in a function to get boolean value and then use that boolean to retrieve or throw exception like you did in your question if($item == null), only in my case it was if(function()) db::table()->where()->first() else throw exception, i will update the answer