# cannot show data from model object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to change the data absent but an error appears 'Trying to get the property' id 'of non-object' I do not understand why even though I have done it before and it's fine. and my relationship table is in apache MySql so my model is blank.
I've tried to match my other edit method but nothing is wrong

this my edit()

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $absensi = absensi::find($id);
        $dataSiswa = DB::table('absensis')
            ->join('siswas', 'siswas.id', '=', 'absensis.idSiswa')
            ->select('absensis.*', 'siswas.nama')
            ->where([
                ['siswas.id', $absensi->idSiswa],
            ])->first();

        return view('absensi.edit', ['absensi'=> $dataSiswa]);
    }
```

and then this is my blade

```
<div class="card-header">
            <h1>Edit Data Absensi </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
        <form action="/absensi/{{$absensi->id}}" method="POST" name="form1" >
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="usr">Nama :</label>
                <input type="text" value="{{$dataSiswa->nama}}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="usr">Semester :</label>
                    <select name="semester" class="form-control" id="sel1">
                        <option value="genap"@if ($dataSiswa->semester=="ganjil") selected @endif>ganjil</option>
                        <option value="ganjil"@if ($dataSiswa->semester=="genap") selected @endif>genap</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input  type="hidden" class="form-control" name="kelas" value="{{$dataSiswa->kelas}}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment">izin:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="izin" value="{{$dataSiswa->izin}}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment">Sakit :</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="sakit"  value="{{$dataSiswa->izin}}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment">Tanpa Keterangan :</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tanpaKeterangan"  value="{{$dataSiswa->izin}}">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Submit" name="Submit">simpan perubahan</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$absensi = absensi::find($id);
```

to

```
$absensi = absensi::findOrFail($id);
```

i think the problem is that the model cannot find the record with that id

and if thats not the case then

```
$dataSiswa = DB::table('absensis')
            ->join('siswas', 'siswas.id', '=', 'absensis.idSiswa')
            ->select('absensis.*', 'siswas.nama')
            ->where([
                ['siswas.id', $absensi->idSiswa],
            ])->first();
```

to

```
$dataSiswa = DB::table('absensis')
            ->join('siswas', 'siswas.id', '=', 'absensis.idSiswa')
            ->select('absensis.*', 'siswas.nama')
            ->where([
                ['siswas.id', $absensi->idSiswa],
            ])->first();

if(!$dataSiswa) {
    // throw new notfound exception here or return back
}


return view('absensi.edit', ['absensi'=> $dataSiswa]);
```

In other words you are trying to access a property of a null object because the queries you made are returning a null object, and on your blade you are tying to access a null object property

Comment: wait, it show another error 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::firstOrFail()'

Comment: which version of laravel are you using

Comment: hmm... the problem is that you are using db table, and the firstOrFail methods is not available there, I've updated the question to include that, but if you want to implement the first or fail method also for the DB facade use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098132/laravel-query-builder-firstorfail

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into defining your relationships with eloquent instead as per [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships).

Once that's done you can use Eloquent to query your table like so:

```
$abensis = abensis::findOrFail($id);
$dataSiswa = $abensis->siswa;
return view('absensi.edit', ['absensi'=> $dataSiswa]);
```